# z-index issue on before element

Tags: jquery, html, css, less

I am having an issue with a z-index on a before element. It currently sits in front of the slides but need it to sit behind it.

I have tried to order the z-indexes of the elements but no luck.

https://codepen.io/mattbmoneypenny/pen/OEPPPG

```js
$('.timeline-slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '130px',
});
```

```css
//Variables//

@white: #FFF;
@dark: #333;
@grey: #CCC;
@orange: #eb5b27;
@yellow: #fea30c;
@os: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
@lato: 'Lato', sans-serif;

.cf {
  clear: both;
}

.slick-slide {
    outline: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.slick-current {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#timeline {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  .container {
    max-width: 1020px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    h2 {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: @os;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 32px;
      color: @dark;
    }
    .timeline-container {
      max-width: 960px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding-top: 60px;
      &:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        margin-top: 30px;
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, @orange, @yellow);
        height: 0.5px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 5;
      }
      .timeline-slider {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
        display: block;
        &:before {
          content: "";
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0px;
          top: 0;
          height: 100%;
          width: 120px;
          background: linear-gradient(90deg, @white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
          z-index: 999997;
        }
        &:after {
          content: "";
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          right: 0px;
          top: 0;
          height: 100%;
          width: 120px;
          background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), @white);
          z-index: 999997;
        }
        .slick-arrow {
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translateY(-50%);
          font-size: 0;
          border: 0;
          padding: 0;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          z-index: 999998;
          outline: 0;
          cursor: pointer;
          transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
          &.slick-next {
            right: -40px;
            background: @yellow;
            &:hover {
              background: darken(@yellow, 20%);
            }
            &:before {
              content: "";
              border-top: 1px solid @white;
              border-right: 1px solid @white;
              width: 15px;
              height: 15px;
              transform: rotate(45deg);
              display: block;
              position: relative;
              left: 7px;
            }
          }
          &.slick-prev {
            left: -40px;
            background: @orange;
            &:hover {
              background: darken(@orange, 20%);
            }
            &:before {
              content: "";
              border-top: 1px solid @white;
              border-left: 1px solid @white;
              width: 15px;
              height: 15px;
              transform: rotate(-45deg);
              display: block;
              position: relative;
              left: 15px;
            }
          }
        }
        .slide {
          text-align: center;
          padding: 10px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          font-family: @os;
          font-weight: 300;
          color: @dark;
          font-size: 16px;
          line-height: 22px;
          outline: 0 !important;
          strong {
            font-family: @os;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: @orange;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            display: block;
          }
          img.full-img {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
          }
          &.full-block {
            .block {
              box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px -2px rgba(204,204,204,0.75);
              border-radius: 10px;
              padding: 20px;
              strong {
                color: @dark;
                font-weight: 700;
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 0;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="timeline">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>A journey xxxx</h2>
    <div class="timeline-container">
      <div class="timeline-slider">
        <div class="slide full-block">
          <strong>2014</strong>
          <div class="block">
            <img class="full-img" src="http://mpadverts.azurewebsites.net/about-timeline/open.png" alt="US Office Open"/>
            Our US office <strong>opens</strong> in Charlston, South Carolina
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide full-block">
          <strong>2015</strong>
          <div class="block">
            Our US office <strong>opens</strong> in Charlston, South Carolina
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide full-block">
          <strong>2016</strong>
          <div class="block">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit diam, felis placerat vitae penatibus ac commodo ad.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide full-block">
          <strong>2014</strong>
          <div class="block">
            Our US office <strong>opens</strong> in Charlston, South Carolina
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide full-block">
          <strong>2013</strong>
          <div class="block">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit diam, felis placerat vitae penatibus ac commodo ad.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide full-block">
          <strong>2014</strong>
          <div class="block">
            Our US office <strong>opens</strong> in Charlston, South Carolina
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please don't repeat yourself. Instead, pare your code down to a [mcve] so it's easier to read and you won't have too much code for your question content.

Comment: please don't spam us, please don't spam us, please don't spam us, please don't spam us, please don't spam us...

Comment: Well im very sorry but ive never used this before

Answer (score 1):

For basic setup of z-index in relation with position, see attached code snippet.
I have intentionally added two squares with green since according to your code you might want to block the divs in a certain depth pattern.

In order to get the correct layout in your webpage, you might need to elaborate with "position: absolute", and "position: relative".

When you have built up your base, add the "before" and "after" - pseudo-elements.

```css
.box-red {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box-green-1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box-green-2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 170px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box-blue {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 100px;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-red"></div>
<div class="box-green-1"></div>
<div class="box-green-2"></div>
<div class="box-blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. There was no background color set on the slides so there wasn't actually a z-index issue, just looked like there was.